# Find all hyperlink from a textarea and add rel nofollow

Tags: javascript, html

I have textarea element. When a user type some HTML code inside the textarea and try to save the code, the function should automatically find all hyperlink and add rel=nofollow attribute.

I have update the function the according to given example, however this is giving me the url value in alert.

```
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById` returns at most only one element. So the `[0]` subscript will result in `undefined` being set to `rel_attribute` and also `setAttribute` would error out since it is being called on undefined. Remove the `subscript` and check.

Comment: If I remove the [0], the function does not work

Comment: Panther is right. Furthermore you has a spelling mistake too `rel_attribute` was defined and then you using `relattribute` without underline. This would still lead to a mistake anyway. And `var add_rel = ` you dont need...

Comment: sorry for the typo, but still this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById` returns single element not an array. Use `.value` to get the content of `textarea` and then you can use `DOMParser` to convert string into `DOM`.

```js
function addrel() {
  const rel_attribute = document.getElementById('textarea_code').value;
  const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rel_attribute, 'text/html');

  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach((a) => {
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    console.log(a);
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea_code"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="addrel()">Add Attribute</a>
```

Edit ---

```js
function naming() {
  var rel_attribute = document.getElementById('textareaCode').value;
  var dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(rel_attribute, 'text/html');
  [...dom.getElementsByTagName('a')].forEach((a) => {
    a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
    alert(a.outerHTML);
  });
}
```

```html
<textarea id="textareaCode"></textarea>
<a href="#" onclick="naming()">Add Attribute</a>
```

Comment: this code is working here, but on my page it is giving url value as an alert

Comment: Please add your code, without looking at code it is difficult to find issue.

Comment: Too long code. Comment section will not accept the code

Comment: please check now

Comment: Its adding rel in console, but it's not replacing the previous value in textarea

Comment: @SwapnilRajja - You have added lot of unnecessary code as well make sure to add code in proper format as it consume more time to dive in code. In order to display in alert use `a.outerHTML`. It will not replace your `textarea` automatically. You need to assign it to the `textarea` value.

Comment: You seems to be genius. Thank you for your help